# Can a web application control native OS controls?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web-applications

I have been making web apps in mobile for some time. One major problem that I have noticed is various native OS controls for either ios or android like keypad, Next button or Done button in a keypad, number pad, drop down box , drop down box font  etc cannot be effectively controlled via the web application. It seems every mobile OS has their own way of dealing with such issues  and developers cannot control them.

Can anybody share some info on this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question seem to be different from the actual question, since the actual question is ambiguous, I'll only answer the title question.

The short answer is no, by developing a web apps, you effectively given up on native behavior for something that approximate it with varying success. I don't know any framework that supports both HTML5 and native UI elements, since they simply don't mix together - all of your HTML5 stuff would be put in a WebView container while native UI elements would either be in front of or behind that WebView, with no real knowledge of each other.

Having said that, for frameworks like PhoneGap, there are some plugin that may provide you with more interaction with the native platform. However, many of them only target one platform, so your code would become fragmented, which kinda defeats the purpose of writing web apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was trying to know. May be my question was not very understandable, but you understood it correctly.